# Sublime Text 2 like block highlighting in emacs

Tags: emacs, configuration, sublimetext

Is there an emacs plugin which creates these nice vertical lines for the code blocks like in Sublime Text 2? (See attached screenshots for what I mean).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see highlight-indentation:

https://github.com/antonj/Highlight-Indentation-for-Emacs/

Unfortunately the current version is very simple and it draws character-wide columns instead of thin lines so it doesn't look very appealing. But at least it's a start.

I do not use it by default - if I'm lost then I do `M-x highlight-indentation`.

Comment: I just got it from elpa. This is what I want. At least it's a start. I hope this will be improved soon.

Comment: The column marker is very thick. Isn't it possible make it a little bit thinner?

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite the same thing, but you get a similar benefit from the features mentioned here:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightCurrentColumn

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VlineMode

Vline can use a thin line (or a face). Column-marker highlighting stays put (doesn't move with the cursor), and you can highlight any number of columns, but it uses a face, not a thin line.